# Safe way to interact with page's DOM from Overlay JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I have a Firefox extension that detects whenever a page loads in the browser and returns its `window` and `document`. I want to attach some events (that launch functions in my addon's overlay) to elements in the page, but I don't know how to do this in a way that's safe.

Here's a code sample:

```
var myExt = {
    onInit: function(){
        var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");
        if(appcontent){
            appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, true);
        }
    },

    onPageLoad: function(e){
        var doc = e.originalTarget;
        var win = doc.defaultView;

        doc.getElementById("search").focus = function(){
            /* ... 'Some privelliged code here' - unsafe? ... */
        };
    }
};
```

So can anyone tell me what's the safe way to add these events/interact with the page's DOM?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to listen to the `focus` event, not replace the `focus()` function:

```
doc.getElementById("search").addEventListener("focus", function(event)
{
  if (!event.isTrusted)
    return;

  ...
}, false);
```

Usually, there is fairly little that can go wrong here because you are not accessing the page directly - there is already a [security layer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCNativeWrapper) (which is also why replacing the `focus()` method will have no effect). You can also make sure that you only act on "real" events and not events that have been generated by the webpage, you check `event.isTrusted` for that like in the example code. But as long as you don't unwrap objects or run code that you got from the website, you should be safe.